# Unable to install published GitLab private package

Tags: npm, gitlab

I successfully published a package in a private GitLab repository of my organisation. In my global and local **.npmrc** configuration file I have the following:

```
# Set URL for your scoped packages.
@<main-package-name>:registry=https://gitlab.<my-organisation-domain>/api/v4/packages/npm/

'//gitlab.<my-organisation-domain>/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken'="<my-token>"

'//gitlab.<my-organisation-domain>/api/v4/projects/<my-project-id>/packages/npm/:_authToken'="<my-token>"
```

In the **package.json** file I have the following properties:

```
  "publishConfig": {
    "@<main-package-name>:registry": "https://gitlab.<my-organisation-domain>/api/v4/projects/<my-package-id>/packages/npm/"
  },
  "name": "@<main-package-name>/<library-name>",
  ...
```

On the GitLab Package and Registry project's page, it says the following:

> **Installation**
>
> `npm i @<main-package-name>/<library-name>`
>
> **Registry setup**
>
> `echo @<main-package-name>:registry=https://gitlab.<my-organisation-domain>/api/v4/packages/npm/ >> .npmrc`

I added `"@<main-package-name>/<library-name>": "~0.0.11"` to the project's package.json, but when I try and run npm install I get:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@<main-package-name>/<library-name> - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@<main-package-name>/<library-name>@~0.0.11' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /path/to/log
```

It seems it's trying to fetch the package from npmjs instead of the specified GitLab registry. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the local **.npmrc** in the project where I was requesting the package and keeping just the global one in my home solved the issue, for some very weird reason.

Comment: I am trying to install private package from gitlab, but not able to install it via yarn

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is a problem of encoded url, check if you not have %2f in the url which not found between your scope and package name

For me it was a problem of my virtual host configuration of gitlab

I have add the following lines and that fix my problem:

AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

AllowEncodedSlashes On

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).